# How to hide relationship columns in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a statement like this:

```
App\User::with('client')->find(2)->makeHidden('client.phone_no');
```

I want to hide certain columns from a relation, but I can't do that with [`makeHidden()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HidesAttributes.html#method_makeHidden), because it only takes the arguments for the `Model` not the relation.

How can I hide some columns from the relation?

Comment: is this a response to an api right ?

Comment: Yes, response for an api@Leorent

Comment: While looking for some more information, I also found [this elaborate but effective](https://medium.com/@InaniT0/sometimes-when-querying-some-models-we-want-to-exclude-colmuns-from-the-results-the-same-as-using-b2001af4b0ec) method

Comment: What type of relationship is `client`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir [hasOne](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOne.html)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you don't want to hide the `phone_no` for all the requests by adding it to the `hidden` property, you could do something like this:

```
$user = App\User::with('client')->find(2);
$user->client->makeHidden('phone_no');
return $user;
```

As I stated in my comment to the original question: I found [this](https://medium.com/@InaniT0/sometimes-when-querying-some-models-we-want-to-exclude-colmuns-from-the-results-the-same-as-using-b2001af4b0ec) method as well. I believe this should be the method you should use when you want to exclude columns more often. If you only want to exclude a column once, my solution should be sufficient.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest approach since it has no extra hassle of subquerying and a dedicated scope. However as @JonasStaudenmeir pointed out, the`with()` call is redundant here.

Comment: @Eisenheim Not completely. If you're going to load the client, might as well eager load it. The second call to client will use the already loaded client.

Answer (score 13):

You can either hide the column in the query result (eager loading is unnecessary):

```
$user = User::find(2);
$user->client->makeHidden('phone_no');
```

Or you don't even get it from the database:

```
$user = User::with('client:id,user_id,...' /* other columns except phone_no */)->find(2);
```

Comment: The second method doesn't work. Returns `null` as the value of `client`

Comment: Is `user_id` the foreign key column in the `clients` table? Did you include it in the selected columns?

Comment: You can't select the `client` without the `user_id`, so you have to use `->makeHidden()` or `Client::$hidden`.

Answer (score 6):

With accepts a callback to modify the query.

```
$users = User::with(['client' => function($query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'name']);
    }])->find(2);
```

You could also define default hidden attributes on your Client model

```
protected $hidden = ['phone_no'];
```

Comment: Returns null for client: `client: null`

Comment: depending on how this relationship is setup you may not be selecting the 'key' that links these models ... if client belongs to user you would need to be selecting that foreign key

Comment: @lagbox You're right. If I don't specify a foreign key, I get null. But if I do specify the FK, it does work:
`\App\User::with(['client' => function($query){$query->select(['user_id','name']);}])->find(2);` But I don't want to reveal the `user_id` either...

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `scope` in your model and apply it in builder

Define these functions in your model

```
protected function columns(){
    return Schema::getColumnListing('clients');
}

public function scopeExclude($query, $value = array()) 
{
  return $query->select( array_diff( $this->columns(), $value) );
}
```

Now use it in query builder

```
App\User::with(['client' => function($query){
    $query->exclude(['phone_no']);
}])->find(2)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because this filters the column while querying the database. And other methods are querying for all columns and filtering afterward which is not a good idea I guess.